# Program or website to monitor for changes in source code of a website

Tags: windows-7, website, network-monitoring

I'm looking for a way to monitor a webpage for changes in its source code. I'd want to get an alert whenever a specific string appears in its HTML.

So far, I've tried the Distill plugin for Firefox, but didn't seem to have a way to directly check the website's source.

I also found some various websites that could send you an alert whenever a webpage changes, but none of them had the feature to check for a specific string in the source.

Anyone know of a way I can do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you the host's administrator, or do you have CRON access?

Comment: I don't have either.

Comment: In this case, your most efficient solution may be to transfer the full website locally.  Using a FTP program such as FileZilla would allow you to easily see which files were changed when doing the transfer (after the first time, of course).

Comment: @Eriek There's one URL you'd like to monitor and see if it contains a specific string, right? You don't even need to compare to a previous version, just see if that string appears whenever you check the page. Do you want to run this monitoring on your own machine? Are you on Windows, Mac or Linux?

Comment: @Atzmon Yes, that's right. I'm on Windows 7.

Comment: Try asking at: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a PowerShell script to get a URL and check if its source contains a string. In this example we're searching for the string "twitter" at https://stackoverflow.com:

```
$URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
$data = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL
if ($data.RawContent -like '*twitter*') { write-host "Found" }
```

Save this text with a `.ps1` extension and you can run it from a PowerShell console. You can also set a Windows scheduled task to run it and do something with the output.